# MYSQL Query works direct but not via PHP!

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following error pop up on the PHP page.  This is the result of echoing out $flightquery just before the query takes place.

```
INSERT INTO Flights (`adshex`,`flightno`,`route`) VALUES ('01002F','MSR845','HECA-DAAG') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT flightno FROM Flights WHERE `flightno` = 'MSR845' AND `adshex` = '01002F' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`timestamp`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 360);

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT flightno FROM Flights WHERE `flightno` = 'MSR845' AND `' at line 1
```

If I copy the insert statement into the MYSQL server it works with no errors but through a PHP it breaks!

```
  $flightquery = "INSERT INTO Flights (`adshex`,`flightno`,`route`) VALUES ('$adshex','$flightno','$route') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT flightno FROM Flights WHERE `flightno` = '$flightno' AND `adshex` = '$adshex' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`timestamp`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 360);";
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed it to errno and it is 1064 which is reserved keywords, where am I doing that?  timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL syntax for INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) there can be no `WHERE` clause with `INSERT`.

Comment: Oh yes!  Well is there a solution for a conditional insert then for MySQL 5 at all?  Even if it requires a different structure!

Comment: If you're just worried about primary key / unique constraint violations, then `INSERT IGNORE` will do the trick.  Otherwise, you should open a transaction, do a `SELECT COUNT` for your criteria, and only insert if there are no matching rows.  Just be prepared to deal with a deadlock or a pkey/unique error, should another process be doing the same thing at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

got the bad boy remove `;` after `360)`,

Comment: No difference at all same error, and surely the error is earlier in the statement as said by the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't work in MySQL Server because there are PHP variables.

**$adshex, $flightno, $route**

```
"INSERT INTO Flights (`adshex`,`flightno`,`route`) 
VALUES ('$adshex','$flightno','$route') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT flightno FROM Flights 
    WHERE `flightno` = '$flightno' AND `adshex` = '$**adshex**' 
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`timestamp`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 360);
```

Comment: But if you look at the top box there are no variables and this is the echoed out $flightquery

Comment: They're variables inside a double-quoted string. PHP expands these automatically. It's a huge security no-no, but it does work, kind of.